# Pentaho Filter Rows sends a single null Row to output

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I´m using Pentaho 8.1 and have a problem on filter rows step.

It´s testing a value on a certain field and if its true go to an output step.

The problem is when any row satisfy filter criteria. I expect not to be done, but instead, is an single row of null field values being send to output

Anybody have already seen this ?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you share with images or the KTR, what exactly is it you're testing for ?

Comment: @CristianCurti thanks. 

I've put the image on the post. I circled the steps with  red circles. There is a simple filter a single field from pmb_base_input I´m testing is equal 'E'. In my case there is no row with this flag, then I was expecting nothing to be done. But even thoght a null row has been sent to the output

Comment: In the rest of the transformation, you have a Group by, in any of the grouped rows are you using the option 'First value' or 'Last value' ? Or any of the Fields that make each group is a Null ? This could feed a Null row in the stream. If a Null is reaching the Group by, it got through the Filter, so maybe you can add a "NOT NULL" test in the existing filter, or add another filter down the stream, with a "NOT NULL" clause to make sure none gets to output.

Comment: @CristianCurti problably not. As a test I kept only the filter steps part and removed all other steps and I've gotten the same error

Comment: @CristianCurti I solved the problem. In group by step there is an option "Always give back a result row" it's checked. As the filter step before it didn't output any row, the "Always give.." option is generating a null row. So I used a Detect Empty Stream step to prevent it and it worked well in my use case